# SQL Authenticated users can't access database

Tags: sql-server, users, visual-studio

I have just created a user account with SQL authentication with username: test1 and password of password. When I log into this account via the server explorer in Visual studio it is fine. Until I click Tables to get a list of tables in the database and it says:

> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>
> Failed to connect to server (local).
>
> Login failed for user 'test1'.

I have created this user with all permissions and it owns the database. But when I log into it with Windows authentication it works fine.

Comment: Weird, when I log in I can see all your tables.

Comment: You might confirm that you have this new login defined with some level of access to the database which you want it to access. I assume you'd need to give it SELECT access to at least one table in the DB for it to be able to expand the tables from the DB. So try granting it select to at least one table and then see if you can expand that table from the VS interface. Once you make the adjustments, close VS and reopen it and then try again just in case. You did not say what version of VS or SQL Server you are running as that may be helpful to know.

Comment: How you create the user 'test1'? In SSMS? Use SSMS, log in as user 'test1' to check what test1 can do.

Answer (score 0):

Your server authentication mode may be set to Windows only instead of Mixed Mode, which will allow Windows logins and SQL logins. If true then the SQL login will not work.

In SQL Server Management Studio, you can right-click on the server and then go to the properties. Then go to security and see how the server security is configured. You can change it there also. If it is set to Windows only then you will have to use a Windows login.

If you want to change to mixed mode to use SQL login, you can make the change but that may require the instance to be reset to take affect.

Comment: It is enabled. As I said it will log me in but When I try to access tables it comes out with that error.

Answer (score -3):

It said can not connect to server 'local', maybe you should grant test1@localhost as well.

Comment: How would I do this? All I see are results for MySQL